# VLC Command Line: --clone-vout-list not working as expected - Open 2 OpenGL Windows

Tags: command-line, video, vlc-media-player, clone

i would like to play a video with VLC on 2 monitors simultaneously. In the command line help the following is described about cloning:

Clone video filter (clone) Duplicate your video to multiple windows and/or video output modules --clone-count= Number of clones Number of video windows in which to clone the video. --clone-vout-list= Video output modules You can use specific video output modules for the clones. Use a comma-separated list of modules.

So, I tried the following command-line options:

```
vlc.exe --video-splitter=clone --clone-count=2 S:\ExampleVideos\Performance_Test1080p60_ProRes422.mov
```

These arguments opened 2 separate "Direct3D Output" windows. But they can't play my videos 100% smoothly. After some googling I found out that this should work better with OpenGL.

Since OpenGL is also supported by VLC, I tried the following options:

```
vlc.exe --video-splitter=clone --clone-vout-list=glwin32,glwin32 S:\ExampleVideos\Performance_Test1080p60_ProRes422.mov
```

and

```
vlc.exe --video-splitter=clone --clone-count=2 --clone-vout-list=glwin32 S:\ExampleVideos\Performance_Test1080p60_ProRes422.mov
```

Now VLC was able to play my video smoothly, but only 1 output window would open at a time.

How can I achieve, that VLC opens 2 cloned OpenGL windows?

Answer (score 0):

Know this question is ages old, but I run into the same problem on Linux just now. I found the answer in the source code (https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob;f=modules/video_splitter/clone.c) where VOUTSEPARATOR is #defined as ':' Your 1st guess was close, just use colon instead of comma as list separator in the --clone-vout-list parameter.